# Can the allocator of `std::pmr::map` be used by container elements for their allocations?

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

Say we have an `std::map` as follows:

```
std::pmr::map<std::string, std::unint8_t> test;
```

How can memory for `std::string` be allocated by the polymorphic allocator of the `std::map` rather than by `std::allocator`?

I know that if we use `std::pmr::string`, the container elements will use the allocator of the container. But I want to make it work with `std::string` as the key type.

I read about [`std::scoped_allocator_adaptor`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/scoped_allocator_adaptor), but not sure how to use this.

Any example would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It can't be done with `std::string` as the key type. `std::string` aka

```
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>
```

uses `std::allocator<char>` to allocate its memory. This allocator **always** calls `operator new` to allocate. You need to change the static type of the container elements from `std::string` to something else to use another allocator.

As you mentioned, the solution is to use `std::pmr::string`, which uses `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<char>` to allocate its memory. This allocator can propagate through a container, so the elements use the same allocator instance as the container itself.

`std::scoped_allocator_adaptor` won't help you here.